# Syntax highlighting iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, syntax-highlighting

I am searching a syntax highlighter for iphone. I've search in this forum and in google, and I have found several answers, but I can't find the answer that I'm searching.

I want a library or a framework that can be imported to my project that includes syntax highlighting for the more languages possible, but the most important is objective-c. I would prefer if it's not in a UIWebView.

Sorry if the question isn't very exact, I'm pretty new in ios development, ask me by the comments if you need more information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try [OkudaKit](http://parsekit.com/okudakit/) or [UKSyntaxColoredTextDocument](http://www.zathras.de/programming/sourcecode.htm).

Not sure if they will compile for iOS, but I think these are your best guesses...

Otherwise, try [ParseKit](http://parsekit.com/), and do the syntax highlighting part yourself with [NSAttributedString](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSAttributedString_Class/Reference/Reference.html).